# How to install Boilerpipe on Windows?

Tags: java, netbeans, web-scraping, web-mining, boilerpipe

Can anyone tell me how to use boilerpipe on windows with Netbeans ? I'll be grateful if you can give me some java code to start with it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to look at their [Wiki](http://code.google.com/p/boilerpipe/w/list) and their [QuickStart](http://code.google.com/p/boilerpipe/wiki/QuickStart). Sample code below...

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
    URL url;
    url = new URL("http://www.example.com/some-location/index.html");

    // NOTE We ignore HTTP-based character encoding in this demo...
    final InputStream urlStream = url.openStream();
    final InputSource is = new InputSource(urlStream);

    final BoilerpipeSAXInput in = new BoilerpipeSAXInput(is);
    final TextDocument doc = in.getTextDocument();
    urlStream.close();

    // You have the choice between different Extractors

    // System.out.println(DefaultExtractor.INSTANCE.getText(doc));
    System.out.println(ArticleExtractor.INSTANCE.getText(doc));
}
```